How to adjust poition of a grouped bar in a stacked barplot?
I have made a grouped barplot. There is one condition in my data that only requires a single ungrouped bar.
Here is the code I have used:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\definecolor{oxic}{HTML}{2F539B}
\definecolor{anoxic}{HTML}{E5788F}
\definecolor{AB}{HTML}{FF7F00}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define the group plot with a common axis setup
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=2 by 2, % 2 columns and 2 rows
        horizontal sep=1.5cm, % Horizontal space between plots
        vertical sep=1.5cm,   % Vertical space between plots
    },
    height=6cm,
    width=7cm,
    symbolic x coords={9, 3, 1, 0, AB}, % Labels for the x axis
    xtick=data, % Ensure all x ticks are shown
    enlarge x limits=0.2, % Add space between bars and axis
    ybar, % Bar plot
    ymode=log,    
    ylabel style={align=center}, % Y-axis label formatting
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1, draw=none, fill=none},
]

% First plot
\nextgroupplot[
    title={\textit{P. plectorum}}, % Title for the first plot
    ylabel={Ratio}, xlabel={Red Compound}
]
\addplot[fill = oxic!60, draw=none] coordinates {(9, 0.39) (3, 0.85) (1, 0.65) (0, 1.02)}; % Oxic
\addplot[fill =anoxic!60, draw = none] coordinates {(9, 0.07) (3, 0.1) (1, 0.14) (0, 0.12)}; % Anoxic
\addplot[fill = AB, draw= none] coordinates {(AB, 0.81)}; % Antibiotics
\legend{Oxic, Anoxic, Antibiotics}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is my current output:

As you can see in the image (and the code comments), the "oxic" and "anoxic" conditions have the grouped bars. However, there was one condition "Antibiotic" that doesn't have the "oxic"/"anoxic" grouped bar and only has data for one condition. I tried to apply it as a separate \addplot element, but the "AB" label does not appear in the x axis labels. Moreover, the bar seems too far away from the rest of the grouped bars. Is there a way to fix this?
Please note that this is in groupplots as I plan to add more similar plots adjacent to this one.
